# Does there exist a bootable USB key with shred?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, secure-delete

Does anyone know if there exist a bootable USB key with `shred` that detects all harddrives and shreds them automatically?

It would be great if it had a config file, where I could set the `shred` value for `-n`.

Comment: Why shred?  Why not DBAN?  http://www.dban.org/

Comment: @ `shred` is just the one I knew, so I guess any other variation would be fine. Can dban be written to a USB key?

Comment: @Sandra, yes, if you use a tool like [uNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, absolutely, and with a bit of tweaking you can get it to boot to a mode that will wipe everything.  That may be tricky though on a USB device, since DBAN will see the USB drive you are booted from as another drive to wipe.  Usually the wipe all drives option is from a CD.  DBAN is included on sysresccd.org, which has really easy to install to a USB, and has many other tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want DBAN - link to follow

[guide on making a dban usb key](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-dban-to-a-usb-flash-drive-using-windows/)

Answer (score 3):

I always use **[YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)** for such purposes. You can add any bootable ISO-File to your USB-stick. Additionally you can add multiple bootable files to your stick and choose which one to start(with Syslinux). YUMI has many preconfigured boot-options. One amongst them is **DBAN**. Watch out that you do not nuke your USB-Drive.